# Magento2: load attribute using attribute code

Tags: collection, magento-2.1.7, custom-attributes

I am using the below code to load the attribute using attribute code but it's not working:-

```
protected $_attribute;

public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection $attribute,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->_attribute = $attribute;  
   ...  
   }

   $existingAttribute = $this->_attribute
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', $attributecode)
            ->load()
            ->getFirstItem();
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($existingAttribute); echo '</pre>';
```

Can any one help me in this.
It's working fine as below in magento 1

```
$existingAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getResourceCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', $attributecode)
            ->load()
            ->getFirstItem();
        echo $existingAttribute->getId();   
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($existingAttribute); echo '</pre>';
```

Thanks for help in advance;

Comment: Up vote your answer

Comment: Your answer is okay but not that I want to implement in my code because I am working on m2 erp module that need the same code flow that I have mention in my answer. your code only load the attribute.

Answer (score 8):

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository;

protected $productAttributeRepository;


public function __construct(
    ...
    Repository $productAttributeRepository
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
    ....
}
```

Now you can use this like to get product attribute

```
$yourAttribute=$this->productAttributeRepository->get('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
```

Answer (score 5):

> Try to use below code

```
<?php

/*add **\Magento\Eav\Model\Config** in your construct method*/

protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
){
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

/*Now you can get attribute data using*/


$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', Your_Attribute_Code);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($attribute->getData()); exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$eavModel = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');
$attr = $eavModel->load($attributeId);
$attributeCode=$eavModel->getAttributeCode();//Get attribute code from its id
print_r(attributeCode);

 /*Get attribute details*/
$attributeDetails = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attributeCode);
print_r($attributeDetails->getData());
```

Comment: $options = $attributeDetails->getSource()->getAllOptions();
Include this line in second last.